# At least one SSDL artifact is required for creating StoreItemCollection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller

Building an MVC + EF sln with visual studio locally and publishing to a production server works.  Building on the server and publish (Hudson CI server) does not?  The error message is

"At least one SSDL artifact is required for creating StoreItemCollection"

Any ideas?

Thanks

Neil

Comment: I don't think there is enough details in your question to be able to help. The error message indicates that MetadataWorkspace could not be constructed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  object context in scope.

If you are passing `ObjectContext` through method parameter it will not working.
Use scope in context.

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted }))
{
    using (ObjectContext db = new ObjectContext())
    {

    }
}
```